# Where do lucid-updates come from?

Tags: command-line, apt

Considering the following command:

```
# apt-get --simulate --show-upgraded upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
 libimobiledevice0 libpam-ck-connector libparted0debian1
Inst libimobiledevice0 [0.9.7-1ubuntu1] (0.9.7-1ubuntu1.2 Ubuntu:10.04/lucid-updates)
Inst libpam-ck-connector [0.4.1-3ubuntu1] (0.4.1-3ubuntu2 Ubuntu:10.04/lucid-updates)
Inst libparted0debian1 [2.2-5ubuntu5.1] (2.2-5ubuntu5.2 Ubuntu:10.04/lucid-updates)
[...]
```

I can read an *Inst* line as the following:

```
Inst <package> [<oldversion>] (<newversion> Ubuntu:10.04/lucid-updates)
```

Can someone tell me where the **Ubuntu:10.04/lucid-updates** comes from? - Considering an own repository, how is this configurable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read your `/etc/apt/sources.list` you will see some lines there that look like these

```
## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted
```

that is where the updated lists are coming from.

`apt-get` will read that config file when you issue `apt-get update`, download the new package lists and when you issue and `apt-get upgrade` it will download the updated packages for your system based on those lists.

The information for the lists is kept under `/var/lib/apt/lists/*_Release` files

Here is an example from the file `security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-security_Release` in that directory:

```
Origin: Ubuntu
Label: Ubuntu
Suite: oneiric-security
Version: 11.10
Codename: oneiric
Date: Tue, 17 Jan 2012 16:38:19 UTC
Architectures: amd64 armel i386 powerpc
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Description: Ubuntu Oneiric Security
```

So in your case the `Ubuntu` would come from the *Origin* and `10.04` would come from the *Version* and the `lucid-updates` would come from *Suite* keys.

Comment: Hi Bruno, thanks for your fast reply. I do however understand the general process of an _apt-get upgrade_. In this case I'm wondering where _apt-get_ takes the **Ubuntu:10.04/lucid-updates** part from. I cannot explain to myself where especially the **Ubuntu:10.04** part comes from. The last part (lucid-updates) could come from the _sources.list_ file. I hope you can understand my issue now ;)

Comment: Hi timbooo, I have updated the answer with more details on the information you are looking for.